# Loading and Viewing a local (in bundle) pdf within Android App

Tags: android, pdf

I have reviewed and tried numerous versions of this issue to no avail.  I have seen answers as far back as 2011 and as recent as mid-year 2014. Unfortunately, the many partial answers and poorly explained suggestions have created more questions than answers.  I have an Apple App available in the iTunes App Store that performs all that I am trying to do with this Android App.  In the Apple App world viewing a pdf file is relatively easy to perform but I am having a very difficult time accomplishing it in Android.  I admit that I am very limited in my experience at creating Android Apps.

The problem is that I have an Android App with a main activity that has a ListView that lists the titles for about 35 diagrams in pdf format.  Each of these is clickable for viewing in a full screen activity (view).  Each pdf is half page width and anywhere from 1/2 a page to two pages in length.  So the new activity (pdf view) will need to be scrollable.  Since this is an app for phones or pads the new activity (pdf view) needs to be zoomable.  After the user completes their view of the pdf they will need an option to return to the main activity.  The user can then select another diagram for viewing.

The things I have already accomplished are:
-  ListView of diagram titles on main activity 
-  Listener enabled for each entry in ListView
-  New activity (pdf view) is accessed
-  Using putExtras - getExtras for variable passing, is working

Some code (from main activity.java):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String scroll_page = new String("CommonVehicleCodeViolations.pdf");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, scroll_view.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra_scroll_page", scroll_page);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

The diagram title is hard coded for testing purposes.  Now, some code from the new activity (pdf view) 'scroll_view.java':

```
public class scroll_view extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String scroll_page = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            scroll_page = extras.getString("extra_scroll_page");
        }

        int currentPage = 1;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        try {
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), scroll_page);
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

            if(currentPage < 0) {
                currentPage = 0;
            } else if (currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
                currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
            }

            renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), new Matrix(),PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This was an attempt to use one of the many already posted answers which suggested using PdfRenderer.  What I get from this example is the new activity (pdf view) blank screen.  I am hoping that 2015 will bring new answers.  Please help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: If you will read the title of the post, I am not able to get the pdf loaded and viewed in the scroll_view activity.  The example that I have shared does not achieve this.  I do not know why.

Comment: I did read the title of the post. The title of the post is also not a question. Beyond that, are you getting any stack traces in LogCat from your exception handler?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using an intent and let the system show you a list of compatible apps:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), scroll_page);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Kristy, I am trying to keep all functions self contained in the app due to tablets not having an active internet connection when out and about.  The users of this app are law enforcement officers who are driving around to accomplish their job.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: You don't need internet access to access installed apps on the tablet.